# MYSQL Get the first date who is active

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 date-ranges who will be active if existing if active.

```
     start_date < NOW() AND end_date > NOW()
```

However, I want to get the first date who fulfills the condition.

This is my sql statement

```
    SELECT
             start_date,
             end_date,
            FROM
             test
            WHERE
             start_date < NOW() 
            AND
             end_date > NOW()
```

But it gives me 2 date - ranges.

```
[1] 2013-03-10 00:00:00 - 2016-01-10 00:00:00
[2] 2012-03-10 00:00:00 - 2016-01-10 00:00:00
```

I only want to get the first occurenct which is [2] the one who started on 2012.

Any help about this?

Comment: Should I order them by start_date?

Comment: I'd suggest `ORDER_BY start_date` and `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Thanks man. I also figured it out while writing this question. :)

Comment: Look up "rubber duck debugging" ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
             start_date,
             end_date,
            FROM
             test
            WHERE
             start_date < NOW() 
            AND
             end_date > NOW()
           ORDER_BY start_date  LIMIT 1
```